# Damage when drilling a mirror — normal or not?

Tags: drill, glass, mirror

I've just had a bespoke mirrored bathroom cabinet installed. The mirrors have had holes drilled for the knobs, and one of the holes has a white mark around it and generally doesn't look very clean. The mark is visible even when the knobs are in place.

The cabinet maker tells me "such a white mark around the cut out in the mirror is normal. It's very difficult to cut through the mirror with a very clean cut".

Is my cabinet maker correct, or should I ask for a new mirror?

See pictures:

[image].

[image: bad hole in mirror]

Comment: Drilling glass is super hard.  I'm amazed they could do it.  Best option is some sort of erosion method like a waterknife.

Comment: Drilling glass without damaging it certainly is difficult. There are [special bits](http://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-1-2-in-Diamond-Drill-Bit-RD-71104/202528417) for cutting glass, and it should be done on a drill press, not by hand, to ensure a perfect right angle without any cracking or oblong holes. Glass is _far_ less forgiving than wood when it comes to drilling holes. As RedGrittyBrick says, however, part of the cost of the mirror is paying professionals who have the skills and proper tools to do it correctly.

Comment: With the right drill bit, taken slowly and run wet, with suitable backing behind the workpiece, I would expect to do a better job than that myself, depsite only having drilled glass a handful of times.  For small holes [this type work](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-Tile+Glass-Drill-Bit-Pack-3/p/168058)

Comment: There are crack repair glues (like for automotive windshields) that you can use to greatly reduce the appearance of those chips.

Comment: I suggest asking the glass maker for larger handles to hide the cracks.

Comment: @Harper: Some people make it [look easy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_KDslB51FM) - getting the hole started smoothly and in the correct place looks kinda tricky though. Anyone who does this professionally ought to do it well or not at all.

Comment: Have you considered filling in the cracks with something dark?  If the knobs were colored, camouflaging the cracks might be hard, but since the knobs are black I would think they should be pretty concealable.

Comment: @Harper I wouldn't say "super hard", I used to work for a company that built machines *that did this for a living*, the technique is simple: use two bits (one from the top and one from the bottom), spin them at a very high RPM, clamp the mirror to eliminate vibration, spray many dozens of gallons of water *through* the bit and around it to cool the glass, and then bring the bits together (but don't touch). We could drill holes in glass that was 3/4" thick (this mirror is probably 1/3 that) with *no* noticeable defects. Any *reputable* manufacturing company will have a similar technique.

Comment: @BrockAdams There are no cracks on the surface — the surface is smooth. The cracks are inside the glass.

Comment: @supercat There are no cracks on the surface — the surface is smooth. The cracks are inside the glass.

Comment: @SimonKatz: If the cracks reach to the hole, some types of ink might wick inside them.  Alternatively, putting something light on the back of the knobs (do both for symmetry) might make the cracks less visible if they're not filled in with something dark, but I don't know how well camouflaged they'd be.

Comment: @SimonKatz, See if a thin glue will wick.  Alternatively, painting a circle matte black, on both sides, might mask it.

Comment: Try taping over the hole with black electrical tape, remount the knob and then, using a razor, cut the tape to fit the knob.  If you can't get it quite right, remove the knob and cut the tape just a tiny bit smaller than the knob and then remount.  The tape should make the problem vanish, although you might have to do both knobs to make them identical.  And I'd quit using the word Bespoke with this cabinet maker.....

Comment: the doors look crooked too, they tell that's normal as well?

Comment: @AndyT on the contrary drilling most forms of toughened glass isn't possible.  Instead the glass is manufacturered with the holes in place and then the toughening treatment is carried out.  Drilling any glass in a factory set up to do it properly is easy -- look at mass-market bathroom cabinet mirrors (and glass shelves if you can find them that aren't safety glass).

Comment: @ChrisH - {facepalm} I knew there was something about drilling and toughened glass...

Comment: Definitely a botched job, either during the drilling or maybe even overtightening the hardware.  A professional glass shop should be delivering cuts like the right side mirror 100% of the time.

Comment: Sure it's hard to drill through glass. That **is** the reason why you hired a pro to do this. When person without sufficient knowledge and experience attempts to drill a hold through glass, I would say that such marks are normal. And, of course, unsuitable tools. Most power drills cannot be programmed for ultra-low RPMs, for example. Honestly: when I try to drill glass in my amateurish way (borrowing a power drill which I can program to *almost* the right RPM), I make sure that I have spare pieces of glass. That is part of my cost calculation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I used to work for a company that built machines that drilled these holes (though we did it in *much* larger pieces, usually 3/4" to 2" thickness). It's not a hard process, it's slightly expensive, but it's *doable*. The process is basically as follows:

- Use *two* diamond-tipped drill bits to cut the hole (one above and one below);
- Use a water-jet to push water *through and around* the bit to cool the glass;
- Clamp the glass on a tight space (vibration relief);
- Spin the bits *opposite each other* at a high RPM;
- Bring the bits together and cut into *both* sides of the glass at the same time;
- Make sure *not* to smash (read: "crash") the bits together;

In the situation where vibration cannot be controlled, and you don't have an upper and lower bit, the manufacturer would typically use an *ultra-low* RPM (like, 20-30 RPM) which avoids the vibration. This takes longer to cut a hole, but avoids problems.

With *ultra-thin* material (1/8"-1/4") we would use a direct water-jet, we would *literally* push water at 60,000 PSI and blow a hole straight through the glass. This is done by backing the glass with a solid (usually metal) surface with a hole for the jet-stream.

You should end up with a clean-cut hole, and no scarring or scoring - minimal fracturing. We used to build these machines, and this type of scoring is *very* unusual and indicates a faulty machining process. Your cabinet maker likely has *one of these machines* quite possibly from us or a different company.

This is a **defect** (it actually looks like the mirror wasn't adequately cooled, so it fractured). It's plain-and-simple, this is a manufacturing defect, and you can *probably* convince them to send you a new one.

**However,** I would avoid that altogether.

While this may be unsightly *right now*, here's how I would fix it (usually for less than $2.00 at a nearby hardware or crafts store):

- Go to a local hardware store and buy *plastic* (or nylon) washers (you want plastic/nylon so that it doesn't interfere negatively with the glass, handle or paint), you want the OD (outer diameter) to be slightly larger than the total size of the issue, and the ID (inner diameter) to be slightly (but not much) larger than the bolt on the handle, you'll want a small thickness;
- Get a small bottle of whatever colour touch-up paint you like (probably *black* to match the handles), these plastic washers often come in gray, white or black (what you'll find depends on the hardware store), make sure it's a water-based paint (certain oil and lacquer based paints will have a negative reaction with the plastic/nylon washer or the handle), and type that is used on model cars should work fine;
- Paint both sides of the washers;
- Place the washer between the handle and the mirror to cover-up the defect;

If done right, you should be able to eliminate the defect area visibility *entirely*, and you should end up with a visually pleasing result. Depending on the theme of your bathroom, you may opt to get a larger OD on the washer and use an "accent colour" ('hot rod red', for example) to make it "pop" and get a more unique look.

Comment: @SimonKatz It should help reduce the visual displeasure, and if you do it right you can add your own "style" to the room, just make sure to get the *plastic* or *nylon*, that is extremely important. :) (It also fixed the issue without needing to get involved with a back-and-forth war with the manufacturer, because I'm certain they'll continually try to pawn it off on you.)

Answer (score 34):

> **Is my cabinet maker correct**

They are right that drilling clean holes in glass is more difficult than in wood or steel.

In my opinion, they are **not** right to say that visible cracking around the hole is normal.

They are a professional and part of the price they charge is for having the skill, experience and tools to do the job better and quicker than you can. The hole on the right suggests they can get an acceptable result at least 50% of the time. In my opinion, they should have factored into their price the cost of wastage in redoing work where needed.

> **should I ask for a new mirror?**

That's up to you. If you are going to stare unhappily at that defect every time you use that cabinet then you should get it fixed now.

[image]

How you do this is a matter of negotiation - because you probably don't have a written contract that specifies explicitly what constitutes an acceptable hole in the mirror.

Comment: Judging by the pictures the chipping is hidden by the door handles in normal use.  Unless it's severe enough that the handle wobbles - in which case I'd want a replacement on that ground - out of sight out of mind probably should apply.

Comment: @Dan, if you look carefully at the *top* photo, you can see the cracking is visible in the reflection of the back end of the left hand handle. In my personal subjective opinion it is minor which is partly why I wrote that doing anything about it is "up to you". Different people have different ideas about what is OK.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice it in the first picture before you pointed it out.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Thanks, that helps me think about it more clearly. Not sure yet what I'll  do. :-)

Comment: This is why I like doing things myself. Professionals are in a hurry because it affects their profits. Drilling a neat hole in glass is easy _if you take your time_. You are actually _grinding_ your way through the glass. If you do it very slowly with very moderate pressure you don't need all the cooling and you won't cause shatter damage. As others have said you need to do it from both sides (true for all materials, it stops tear out) and a jig to keep you square helps.

Answer (score 9):

The level of cracking you're showing on the left is not normal. There is some roughness around the hole on the right which is generally normal. Actually, the hole on the right is, more or less, what it should look like when you drill a mirror or any glass. This is one of those skills that takes practice to become consistently good at.

As for replacing the mirror, that's your call. If it bothers you, then replace it now as another commenter said, you'll be happier for it. From what I can see in the pictures, I don't think that it is structurally unsound. Meaning, I don't think it will break under normal use due to the mediocre quality of the hole.

Comment: Yup, I fouled up when I was typing. Thanks for catching it. I've edited the answer.